# Why is Intel Turbo Boost Not Working On My Laptop?

Tags: windows-7, bios, turbo-boost, speedstep

> **Investigation continued**
>   [Why is Intel Turbo Boost Not Working On My Laptop? (Continued)](https://superuser.com/questions/323726/why-is-intel-turbo-boost-not-working-on-my-laptop-continued)

**Dell Latitude E6420** is my laptop with Windows 7 Enterprise. Turbo Boost is enabled in BIOS but is disabled in OS according to AIDA64. I managed to install Intel Turbo Boost Monitor but it says that Turbo Boost is not enabled. Although I still see standard speed but I also see ***"Energy Saver"*** appears when CPU runs at less than standard speed.

What is interesting is that Turbo Boost gets enabled in OS only when SpeedStep is enabled as well in BIOS. This slows down CPU to ~700Mhz and stays there no matter what. Enabling\Disabling C-State did not do anything and there is no multiplier.

Intel Chipset Utility is the latest version and I did not find any Turbo Boost driver, nor any service in Administration.

I have found drivers package for my model **[here](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/Latitude%20E6420%20Windows%207%20Driver%20CAB#fbid=87OyVdSafi1)**. The problem is that i do not know what is responsible for Turbo Boost.

Comment: If you do enable SpeedStep, then Windows reports Turbo Boost is on?

Comment: Another way to monitor Turbo Boost activity: http://www.argusmonitor.com/en/turboboost.php

Comment: Try this Intel turbo boost driver..http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-83556-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=4194790&sw_lang=

Comment: @Doc Yes this is correct.

Comment: Download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and [Prime95](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.extremeoverclocking.com%2Ffile.php%3Ff%3D103&rct=j&q=prime%2095&ei=Br5BTsDrNNS80AGeuPD7CQ&usg=AFQjCNHmaf-S3b1SagcP4-F-C5qH7d1q3g&cad=rja).  Run both, and let us know what the frequency hits.  **Enable *all* power saving features** (including SpeedStep).

Comment: Waht other power saving features are there except SpeedStep?

Comment: @Boris_yo Look for any power-management stuff, or anything related to C-states in the BIOS.

Comment: Which Intel cpu you have in your laptop? I have E6420 with i7 and it does seem to work. Normally core speed is at 798.3 but it does jump to 3000Mhz. Have you updated BIOS? I have A05 version running.

Comment: You have updated to latest version of BIOS A05? I heard bad things about this version. How is it working for you so far?

Comment: Check out my updated answer. I'm not sure if you solved it or not but new BIOS is out and woila (1. Fixed issue where Intel Turbo boost non-functional)

Answer (score 11):

Latest generation Intel processors automatically under clocks your processor in order to save energy when you are not using it. Seeing "Energy Saver" listed under the monitor program is nothing to worry about.

From Intel:

Turbo Boost -

> Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 is activated when the Operating
> System (OS) requests the highest processor performance state (P0).
>
> The maximum frequency of Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 is dependent
> on the number of active cores. The amount of time the processor spends
> in the Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 state depends on the workload
> and operating environment.

Speed Step -

> Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology
>
> Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology is an advanced means of enabling
> very high performance while also meeting the power-conservation needs
> of mobile systems. Conventional Intel SpeedStep Technology switches
> both voltage and frequency in tandem between high and low levels in
> response to processor load

From what I can tell and have seen, these two technologies are highly linked. Turbo Boost is a feature that has come from Speed Step (that has been available for a long time) and enabling Turbo Boost requires Speed Step to be active.

I would say that your BIOS is lying to you and it should disable the ability for Turbo Boost to be changed whilst Speed Step is disabled. From looking at some of the laptops I have on my bench, Speed Step can not even be disabled - it is a good feature that can increase the battery life quite a bit and I am not sure why you would want it disabled.

Also, if you really want to update, go to the official Dell site, type in your asset code and download the latest BIOS/EFI Updates and chipset drivers. I think the BIOS/EFI has the best chance here but, it never hurts to update the chipset drivers either.

Comment: I'm not sure if "idle states" are the same as SpeedStep, but you *can* disable them -- you can unlock the appropriate options in the Power Options dialog and then set them to Off. (Your CPU will no longer idle, so your computer will obviously heat up and it's not good for your CPU.)

Comment: And how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you've got all devices installed in Device Manager
2. Make sure you're updating your Dell from [Dell's website](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/) (which also uses your Service Tag to be able to find the right drivers for your model). Most of the devices in driver pack you linked in your questions are older then the ones you get by directly downloading and installing your updates.
3. Try updating your BIOS. There were lots of fixes in A05 version for E6420 (which I do have as well with I7 processor and it seems to work just fine. )

> 1. Added support for Signed Firmware Updates.
> 2. Additional vPro support. Added DASH ‘PLDM for BIOS Control and Configuration?
> 3. Updated the Password Bypass feature.
> 4. Fixed issue where the system would not reboot the first time after disabling the Integrated NIC in Setup.
> 5. Addressed issues with the 'Auto-On Time' Setup field.
> 6. Fixed issue where a UEFI OS install would fail with greater than 8GB of memory.
> 7. Addressed intermittent boot issues in ATA mode.
> 8. Fixed issue in ATA mode where unaligned memory accesses would fail.
> 9. Fixed issue where the BIOS would reboot instead of flashing when the /S parameter was used with the flash executable.
> 10. Fixed issue where the error log data from the previous POST would show up if you shut down the machine at the F1/F2 prompt.
> 11. Fixed issue where the IDT audio device would not appear in device manager when running a UEFI OS.
> 12. Updated to the MOB_P_08 version of the Intel microcode patch.
> 13. Updated to the 1.3.72 version of the Intel PXE OROM.
> 14. Updated to the 4208 version of ePSA diagnostics

EDIT: Consider updating to newest [BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=CNH63&FileId=2771061108) A08

Changes are:

```
Fixes/Enhancements
1. Fixed issue where Intel Turbo boost non-functional. (sound familiar?)
2. Fixed issue where TDM PBA SSO doesn't work when both FP and TDM PBA SSO are set for single user. 
3. Addressed some keyboard with USB Hub not accessible during POST.
4. Updated to the 1.4.0 version of Intel PPM Reference Code. 
5. Updated to the MOB_P_13 version of the Intel microcode patch. 
6. Intel Trusted Execution Technology updates 
7. Updated to the 1.05 version of Dell GPE. 
8. Added new key for Signed Firmware Updates. 

Note: 1. Please note that if the A04 or before A04 BIOS is currently installed on your system, you must first update to A05 BIOS and then flash to the latest A-rev BIOS.
```

Comment: How BIOS A05 is working for you so far?

Comment: I had no problems. I always update to newest bios when it comes out. If things go bad, really bad (like mobo not working) I'll just call Dell to come in and fix it :-) That's why I always buy 3 years warranty NBD or for crucial situations PRO Support.

Comment: If you still don't have A05 i would upgrade it and see how it works out for you. If you still will experience problems call Dell but they will 99% of times tell you do do BIOS update anyway first.

Comment: And after 3 years you stop updating BIOS or just buy another laptop? What happened with dual BIOS motherboards? If one does not work, use another. The point of failure decreases dramatically.

Comment: Well I consider that in 3 years time they will fix all the problems with BIOS. Having dual BIOS wouldn't do anything. Dual BIOS was for possible failure during bios upgrade or so. There was no "special" BIOS being delivered other then the one by producer. ON the other hand in 3 years time i will most likely buy new laptop anyway. Like any software BIOS requires updates. So just go to their website and update it. If it fixes your problem you're good to go... and you shouldn't worry about next 3 years.

Comment: Just updated bios to A08 and it should fix your issue as per my edited answer.

Comment: I need dual BIOS - everybody needs because it decreases risk of failure so if one BIOS bricks, i have another. A08 is out already? That was fast...

Comment: Yes and it has `1. Fixed issue where Intel Turbo boost non-functional. (sound familiar?)` in it's change log so go and upgrade .. in my answer you've got full change log. I haven't seen bios failure for my lifetime. Of course make sure you've got enough power.

Comment: Enough power? I have UPS and will also put battery just in case. Was that what you meant?

Comment: Ye, like connect your laptop to power outlet and have battery full or so. That should be sufficient. Unexpected power failure can cause what you are afraid to .. a bios crash ;)

Comment: Can this be the only reason for crash? I heard BIOS can be bricked also which has nothing to do with power failure.

Comment: If it's badly prepared BIOS or some crash happens in the middle then sure. Right now most companies use check-sums for BIOS so they check before applying if BIOS is good. But like I said. I haven't had a problem with wrong bios in my life time. Of course you can be the one with bad karma...

Comment: How to check-sum?

Comment: It will be done by program itself. Just run it and that's it.

Comment: Did you upgrade BIOS in Windows environment or MS-DOS? I am trying to upgrade from MS-DOS using MS-DOS 6.22 Boot CD but cannot load my optical drive's driver.

Comment: Windows. Just download it from Dell website and start .exe and that's it.

Comment: Updating in Windows environment is risky. I better do it through MS-DOS. By the way, under which environment Windows Repair Disk operates?

Comment: I don't know where you get that stuff that Windows environment is risky. It's not Windows 95 anymore. Unless you got total messed up Windows with lots of viruses and stuff you are safe to do BIOS updating in Windows. This topic has been running forever now and if you would just run the .exe you would be done with it.

Comment: Are you aware of A12 BIOS update?

Comment: Yes, I've installed it.

Comment: How's A12 working for you. There's A13 already.

Comment: Bummer... Update wen successfully to A08 but it didn't solve Turbo Boost proble which was the sole reason I updated in the first place. Still no Turbo Boost after standby which seems like problem with driver itself than BIOS.

Comment: Why are you back to A08 ? I am at A13.

Comment: No I am not back. I have made update from A04 to A05 and to A08. This is the update where Turbo Boost should have been solved, but it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Why don't you update to A13 then ?

Comment: What for? To hope it will fix something which is unlikely? Besides, I think upgrading should be not every other time there is new BIOS version but to last version in specific series which will allow you to continue updating to next series. For example if I wanted to update to A013, I would only need to perform 2 BIOS updates since A05 and A08 connect me between A01 and A013 and updating version after version would simply be high risk, not to mention waste of time.

Comment: You really need to stop being in 1990. For a guy with a problem you surely are pessimistic to do update that may solve your problem. After all that's what updates are for.. to solve multiple problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4780/discussion-between-boris-yo-and-madboy)

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging in your computer. My turbo boost only works when my computer is charging. I think that the default settings disable it when its not charging. It saves power. Turbo boosting is so nice for games though, try to always play while charging!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8 the CPU monitor would always show the same speed and so would the Intel Turbo Boost monitor, even when I was pushing the CPU.

I went to power options (laptop), and went from power saving to high performance and now the Turbo Boost comes on when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Turbo boost will only work under certain curcomstances.

The first thing that comes to my mind why it "won't work" (note quotation marks) on your laptop is becuase working temperature of your CPU is already high enough and CPU, of course, won't go into destructive mode by overheating himself.
Another thing it might be that your CPU is already at peak TDP (Thermal Design Power) and it won't fire Turbo Boost.

Also you might be at your maximum power consumation.
I'm assuming that Turbo Boost is enabled in BIOS. According to Intel (and my personal experience) - to get it work only thing you have to do is to enable it in your BIOS.

Anyway, and I can stress this enough.

**DON'T OVERCLOCK YOUR LAPTOP(S)** (Turbo boost = overclocking)

Not only it your battery life is shorter, but overall temperature of your system is higher and life of your laptop is shorter.
If anything, you should look how to undercloack CPU. It's not desktop computer, it already has hard time with heat dispersion.

Comment: Turbo Boost is SMART overclocking so it is safe compared to standard overclocking.

Comment: Indeed, that's why it might be a reason why your CPU speed is not higher when Turbo Boost is on.

Comment: I think you're wrong on this one. If the Mhz is at 700 as the OP says it's most likely lowest possible value. I have exactly same laptop and it does jump from 700Mhz to 3000Mhz when I start doing something. Even when I start typing it goes up to 3000Mhz from 783. Also saying he shouldn't overclock his laptop is completly wrong in this case. It's standard Intel feature. If you're not doing anything then your laptop stays at 700Mhz, if you do something it jumps to higher speeds. It does behave differently on Battery and normal Power.

Comment: I still don't see what's the connection between your laptop and his problem. It's not just about having the same CPU. You have to met other condition as well (temperature, power, load, etc.). Yeah, it is Intel's feature (AMD's version is called Turbo Core, it's pretty standard feature in todays CPUs), but it is still basicly OC and if requirements are not met, it won't fire. It's not - "Click the button and it will work" kind of feature. Also, I don't believe simple text editing will force TB to OC CPU to 3GHz. Cold-booting text editor might, on the other hand.

Comment: When simple text editing occurs, then Turbo Boost may kick in but only for a couple of seconds. I did not see it constantly stays at high MHz.

Comment: @StupidOne it's produced to behave like that. If you do anything it jumps high and if doesn't need the power anymore it stops. Comparing it to OC and stating to not overclock your LAPTOP it means you either don't know what the feature is about (and it seems you do from what I can read) or you are misunderstanding the whole purpose of the feature. It's to keep power consumption down as much as possible at times when CPU power is not needed and use it when it is. It has nothing to do with OC.

Comment: @MadBoy - No TB just gives you more power when you need it. SpeedStep and, I believe it's called, Core Parking are two main features which are used for lower power consumation. If declaered speed of CPU is 2000 MHz (let say 20x100), and the TB kicks in, total output speed will be 20x100  (core) + 3*100 (TB). When your CPU is idle and it's working, let say, on 700 MHz. It's not TB who changed it, but SpeedStep - 7x100 (core). NB: I'm not sure about names of features as I'm not so well familiar with Sandy Bridge arhitecture.

Comment: Still it's not overclocking in the old meaning. This is a feature to boost usage. Stating you shouldn't overclock misses by a mile.

Comment: @MadBoy - OC means anything going above your stock value. If the CPU goes even +1 MHz above stock, it's called OC. What TB does is OC. Should you use TB? Yeah, why not? Is it OC? Yes it is. Is OC healthy for laptops? No, it isn't. Is TB healthy? Yes it is, because it's done in a way it can't DMG your CPU in any way. Should I force TB even when it's not firing? NO!!! (that's why I said you should not OC laptops. If it doesn't want to go above X MHz- don't push it). Anyway, OC is also about boost usage. TB is nothing more and nothing less then in-built OC with very rigid safety measures on.

Answer (score -1):

guys just upgrade your power supply to more higher Amp if your are using 65 Watt power supply the bios will tell the OS that your power supply is not capable of delivering the power it need on your cpu and gpu that's why your getting throttle down frequency, because i try using 65 watt power supply then when i start the dell latitude e6420 the bios detected it and warn me and after that i had notice the cpu frequency had been down clock around 800 MHz, then i use 90 watt power supply and it run normally also turn on the turbo boost up to 3.2 to 3.3 GHz but I also notice 90 watt is kind of a bit hot then i try 130 watt power supply then that do the trick the Laptop just work fine at heavy load plus the power supply do not get to much hot even the laptop is on heavy load process or some gaming or doing some stress test. Kinda a bit common sense i7 cpu uses high AMP to work well just give you device good ample of room on power supply even the Manufacturer say this device uses 19.8 V dc and 3.5 amp it is not good if your power supply have that same capacity, yes in short run it will work but your power supply will work crap ton hard just to give that power that is your device needed.

Comment: Have you lost your `.` key?

Comment: People are more likely to read your answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party, I know.

For future search engines pointing folks here, turbo boost is not overclocking. From Intels site it clearly states your os temps will stay the same. For those that do get heat issues and have cleaned there laptop of dust, you may be able to (depending on chip) undervolt your cpu and get full clock speed with 20-30 percent less heat.
Also, in power plan, set min and max cpu to 100 and open task manager under cpu tab and see the frequency change to turbo boost speeds. I keep my max at 100% and minimum speed at 80% keeping me around the base speed and when cpu gets used, full turbo boost speed. I can lower my min and go down way below base clock if I needed too as well.
To turn turbo boost off, change max cpu to 99% and check your clocks in task manager again.
To check temps at the high speeds use cpuid HWMonitor or similar product.
I am trying to see if I even need the new intel turbo boost driver pakage. Everything works and I dont see a previous driver pakage for TB on my system.