# Why is Intel Turbo Boost Not Working On My Laptop? (Continued)

Tags: windows-7, bios, turbo-boost, speedstep

*This is continuation to* ***[previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/321122/why-is-intel-turbo-boost-not-working-on-my-laptop)***

**Please read previous question in order to understand my findings.*

Okay guys, this is REALLY strange. It seems as Intel Turbo Boost was always working, but i could not see it really working until i installed Intel Processor ID Utility.

**[Please watch 1st video](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=1tedU4qOb-g&hd=1)** - Intel Turbo Boost **activated** in BIOS

What is strange is that no other programs can see Turbo Boost but Intel Processor ID Utility and Intel Turbo Boost Monitor. Everytime i launch monitor it states that **i don't have Turbo Boost enabled**, but continues to monitor.

**[Please watch 2nd video](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=DPfwa-zwnKQ&hd=1)** - Intel Turbo Boost **deactivated** in BIOS

And Turbo Boost still works although it is deactivated in BIOS?! How is this possible?

I don't know what to believe now. What if monitor and processor ID lie to me that Turbo Boost is working and other programs don't? I don't have any Turbo Boost stuff in Device Manager which means it is **hidden** and no other programs can see Turbo Boost but Intel's?

AIDA64 CPUID does not show any signs of Turbo Boost - clock rate is ~same, multiplier changes but no further than x25, system bus is ~100MHz.

In the end i have mananged to disable Turbo Boost (i think) but only with having 1 active core, so in other words i cannot disable Turbo Boost with 2 active cores.

I have noticed that when Turbo Boost kicks it, the **screen's brightness changes**. Any idea why?

**Update:** Turbo Boost **[does not work after Standby](https://superuser.com/questions/323858/intel-turbo-boost-does-not-work-after-standby-s3-state)**

Comment: Why did you open another question?  You should have just appended this information to your previous question.

Comment: How do i append? You mean just to update?

Comment: This old question was just revived as a potential duplicate (http://superuser.com/review/close/588527), which was raised at the time of posting.  Questions need to be self contained and single-issue.  Your other question has six answers, so you don't want to change that question if it will make the existing answers invalid or incomplete.  The fact that this is related to the other question doesn't necessarily mean it's a duplicate if the specific issue is different and not covered by the other question and answers.  To keep this question separate, please make it self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what to say...

If you 100% are sure you disabled it in the BIOS, but, it is still happening / being reported, I think you have found a bug in the machine and should report it as such. I have never seen this before.

As for why the brightness changes, Turbo Boost requires a higher power consumption. This could be a badly designed laptop that does not have enough power and there are problems... But, didn't you say somewhere that you are using the wrong power cable?

Comment: William i have added more to this question.

Comment: Still doesn't really make a difference. If it was working at all after setting it to disabled, I think you may have bigger problems

Answer (score 0):

You know, widgets, especially out-of-date ones, tend to show inacurate data...
On the other hand, you have profesional program which is feeding you with more reliable data and you are simple rejecting them?

Use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to check your frequencis when stressing single core (the best tool out there for stressing single core is [Super Pi](http://www.overclock.net/downloads/138140-super-pi.html))

Answer (score 0):

The top one is just showing you the name of your processor, which tells the stats on it too.

The bottom one is actually showing you the speed (not the optimal stats of the processor, but the actual speed it's running at in real time).